# Failed to resolve import Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vite

Hi i am trying to run my program with vue but i am getting this error
`[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./components/authorisation/AuthComp" from "src\router\index.js". Does the file exist?` 
the program cannot find the file in the route.js
router.js file:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    ,{
    path: '/auth',
      name: 'authentication',
      component: () => import('../components/authorisation/AuthComp')
    }]})
```

AuthComp.vue file:

```
export default {
  name: "AuthComp",
  data(){
    return {
      form: {},
      isLoginForm: true,
      errorMsg: ''
    }
  }
```

I don't know where the problem is .

Comment: Try adding the `.vue` extension to the import.  E.g., `import('../components/authorisation/AuthComp.vue')`.